# How to check if gmail id exist or not c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gmail, email

I want to check if a gmail Id exist or not to validate user before registration. We are not willing to send a confirmation link and want to check in code.

Tried so many things like connecting gmail mx account through telnet

```
TcpClient tClient = new TcpClient("gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com", 25);
```

but everytime I get error :

An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 74.125.21.26:25

Comment: You can not check if gmaili exist or not just by making request to some TCP port of gmail. That's a big security risk and Google surely won't allow it. You have two options. 1). Allow user to register using whatever email and try to send verification link without worrying about if the email exist or not. And don't allow user to login without verifying the email id. That way only legit users will be able to login. 2). Integrate with Google for authenticating user. That way you are sure that only valid google users are logging in and you don't need to wory about username and passwords of them.